Joining two objects generates sharp edge

Hello guys,
My problem here is that when I join 2 objects together - the small one below - and do so precisely, there is a sharp edge between the interface (see picture).
Merging and ShadeSmooth did not work.
It is just important for 3D-printing.
Do you know how to solve it? Thanks in advance!
Edit: 

hello it's hard to understand, could you please share your file?

Edit: attached the file for better understanding

It looks as if the topology is pretty horrible on those parts and they don't align closely enough for merging by distance to work unless you increase the Merge distance. Were the parts produced in Blender?

They were made in Catia. Do you think despite this edge it can still be 3d-printed?

For 3D printing you can remesh

Once you export the model from Blender, you can use an app called 3d Builder on Windows to fix up any weird edges and such.
Here's how to repair a 3d model inside of 3d Builder:

Import your 3d model
A red box should appear around your 3d model, check for a notification at the bottom right
Click on the notification which will then repair your model (hopefully)
Then just go to File>Save as and save your repaired 3d model

3d Builder Microsoft Store Link
